# port forwarding causes ICMP unreachable error

Tags: networking, portforwarding, icmp

I have an unusual error whereby I am trying to set up port forwarding. I have port forwarded port 33333 to my static internal IP address. However, when I send a packet to the router I via port 33333 I don't get the packet back. I checked wire shark and the router is sending back a ICMP packet saying Destination unreachable (Port unreachable) when i send it a packet. I am using the virgin home hub,fyi.

All help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the device you are sending to on port 33333 doesn't accept ICMP's on that port. Try doing a port map instead where you map port 33333 to port 0. Also some firewalls block all ICMP's so check to see that there is an allow rule for ICMP's.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your reply. It turned out it was an error in my script. I was sending the packet to the internal IP address of my router instead of the external IP address, which apparently does not work with port forwarding ( I'm not entirely sure why .)

Comment: @joelyboy94 Makes sense since you are outside the network your script doesn't know about your routers internal interface as internal IP are not routable on the internets.